# Unable to Parse a complex Json using Gson

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson

I am dealing with the following response from the server, I need to Gson in order to parse this not so common response:

```
 [  
   {  
      "body":"Some Text",
      "images":[  
         {  
            "height":284,
            "top_image":true,
            "url":"http://www.google.com",
            "width":450
         }
      ],
      "title":"Wow"
   },
   {  
      "body":"Some Text",
      "images":[  
         {  
            "height":200,
            "top_image":true,
            "url":"http://www.url.com",
            "width":600
         }
      ],
      "title":"Voom"
   },
   {  
      "body":"Some Text",
      "images":[  
         {  
            "height":360,
            "top_image":false,
            "url":"http://mobile.com",
            "width":190
         },
         {  
            "height":262,
            "top_image":true,
            "url":"http://noidea.com",
            "width":480
         }
      ],
      "title":"Quarry"
   }
]
```

I have set up the getter and setter as follows:

```
public class Articles {

    public List<Articles> results;

    @SerializedName("body")
    private String body;
    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("images")
    private List<Images> images

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public List<Images> getImages() {
        return images ;
    }

    public void setImages(List<Images> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("***** Articles  *****\n");
        sb.append("BODY=" + getBody() + "\n");
        sb.append("TITLE=" + getTitle() + "\n");
        sb.append("IMAGES=" + getImages() + "\n");
        sb.append("*****************************");

        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

And the Images classes goes as follows:

```
public class Images {

    private String width;
    private String height;
    private String url;
    private String topImage;

    public String getWidth() {
        return width;
    }
    public void setWidth(String width) {
        this.width = width;
    }
    public String getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
    public void setHeight(String height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    public String getTopImage() {
        return topImage;
    }
    public void setTopImage(String topImage) {
        this.topImage = topImage;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return getWidth() + ", "+getHeight()+", "+getUrl()+", "+getTopImage();
    }
}
```

I have tried this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

Articles[] testCase = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Articles[].class);
```

I need some recommendation on how to parse this (complex to me) response using best practices any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I am missing any piece of the puzzle.

Comment: You have an array of images in your response. So I think you should use `private List<Images> images`.

Comment: @MisaghEmamverdi  I agree with that I will edit the code but as far as the response do you have any idea of to fully parse it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MR Mido: Your code works fine.
I just test with newest GSON lib. (2.2.4)

Every data is parsed.

[image]